# Add Photoswipe to table gallery

Tags: gallery, photoswipe

I want to add Photoswipe to a gallery that ive made inside a table. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/baL04a9o/1/embedded/result/) is a sample site.

```
<
```

I want to keep the layout of the gallery but when you click each image it pulls up the Photoswipe viewer, can I do this?

Jfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/baL04a9o/

Answer (score 0):

This is photoswipe gallery with table. [Code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOLzpy)

### First gallery:

```
  <div class="my-gallery" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageGallery">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
    <figure >
      <a href="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2567/5697107145_a4c2eaa0cd_o.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="1024x1024">
          <img src="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2567/5697107145_3c27ff3cd1_m.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
      </a>
                                          <figcaption itemprop="caption description">Image caption  1</figcaption>

    </figure>
    </td>
    <td>

    <figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
      <a href="https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1043/5186867718_06b2e9e551_b.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="964x1024">
          <img src="https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1043/5186867718_06b2e9e551_m.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
      </a>
      <figcaption itemprop="caption description">Image caption 2</figcaption>
    </figure>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>

    <figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
      <a href="https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6175/6176698785_7dee72237e_b.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="1024x683">
          <img src="https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6175/6176698785_7dee72237e_m.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
      </a>
      <figcaption itemprop="caption description">Image caption 3</figcaption>
    </figure>
    </td>
    <td>
    <figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
      <a href="https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5023/5578283926_822e5e5791_b.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="1024x768">
          <img src="https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5023/5578283926_822e5e5791_m.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
      </a>
      <figcaption itemprop="caption description">Image caption 4</figcaption>
    </figure>
    </td>
  </tr>
    </table>

  </div>

<!-- Root element of PhotoSwipe. Must have class pswp. -->
<div class="pswp" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">

    <!-- Background of PhotoSwipe. 
         It's a separate element, as animating opacity is faster than rgba(). -->
    <div class="pswp__bg"></div>

    <!-- Slides wrapper with overflow:hidden. -->
    <div class="pswp__scroll-wrap">

        <!-- Container that holds slides. PhotoSwipe keeps only 3 slides in DOM to save memory. -->
        <!-- don't modify these 3 pswp__item elements, data is added later on. -->
        <div class="pswp__container">
            <div class="pswp__item"></div>
            <div class="pswp__item"></div>
            <div class="pswp__item"></div>
        </div>

        <!-- Default (PhotoSwipeUI_Default) interface on top of sliding area. Can be changed. -->
        <div class="pswp__ui pswp__ui--hidden">

            <div class="pswp__top-bar">

                <!--  Controls are self-explanatory. Order can be changed. -->

                <div class="pswp__counter"></div>

                <button class="pswp__button pswp__button--close" title="Close (Esc)"></button>

                <button class="pswp__button pswp__button--share" title="Share"></button>

                <button class="pswp__button pswp__button--fs" title="Toggle fullscreen"></button>

                <button class="pswp__button pswp__button--zoom" title="Zoom in/out"></button>

                <!-- Preloader demo http://codepen.io/dimsemenov/pen/yyBWoR -->
                <!-- element will get class pswp__preloader--active when preloader is running -->
                <div class="pswp__preloader">
                    <div class="pswp__preloader__icn">
                      <div class="pswp__preloader__cut">
                        <div class="pswp__preloader__donut"></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="pswp__share-modal pswp__share-modal--hidden pswp__single-tap">
                <div class="pswp__share-tooltip"></div> 
            </div>

            <button class="pswp__button pswp__button--arrow--left" title="Previous (arrow left)">
            </button>

            <button class="pswp__button pswp__button--arrow--right" title="Next (arrow right)">
            </button>

            <div class="pswp__caption">
                <div class="pswp__caption__center"></div>
            </div>

          </div>

        </div>

</div>
```